# Objective C: Segue back to root from NSObject class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, segue

I've made an app that's an extension of our companys product. Users login with the same username and password as they would on our product (handled server-side).

Essentially, as the user, you type "stuff" into the app in which you then send to the server. Each call to the server checks if the username and password is correct. (stored in core-data & keychain)

However if we get invalid password as a response (ex. if their superior have changed their password) the user should be removed from the app (I have already written code for this) **AND segue to root view**. <- This is where I'm stuck.

I have an NSObject class XYZUploader.m which handles responses from the server.
Whenever we get the invalid password as a response I want to segue to root.

[image: Overview]

XYZUploader is not a viewcontroller that can be found above. It is just a NSObject class that handles responses (among other things). so a simple:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

does not work. I get the error:

```
Property 'navigationController' not found on object of type 'XYZUploader'
```

I want to link(delegate?) XYZUploader to XYZiPad_Login (root, first viewcontroller above). So that I can call a function to segue back to root **from whatever viewcontroller the user happens to be on at the time**

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register notification in rootviewcontrller, logout method should handle the transition of rootviewcontrller

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(logout)
                                             name:@"InvalidCredentialsNotification"
                                           object:nil];
```

In XYZUploader.m post notification

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"InvalidCredentialsNotification" object:nil];
});
```

Comment: Hey this works great. I get the callback to logout function inside my XYZiPad_Login. But how do I make it segue back to itself (if that makes sense)

Comment: what do you mean by segue back to itself? my understanding of your question is after showing the login screen enter the proper credentials and tap login button it should go to the existing view before logout. is this your question? please explain?

Comment: Simply put: I want the root vc to show when I call the InvalidCredentialsNotification inside XYZUploader.m.

Comment: With some fiddling around I made it work! I had to call [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: inside logout method call [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]; , it will show the roortviewcontroller from any view

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, at any place in your app, a network request might come back with an auth-error, and in that case you want to show the rootViewController.

You do not want to link the downloader directly with the viewControllers in the way you describe. The downloader wants to signal (via e.g. NSNotification, delegate, KVO) that an auth-error occurred and the user is no longer authorized. Then, an object that is in control of the viewController-hierarchy can reorganize the viewController hierarchy. Your viewController now seems simple enough to be able to do this in the appDelegate, but if you expect your app to grow in the coming montsh, you should consider creating a dedicated object that is in charge of making sure the right VC-hierarchy is setup.

Answer (score 1):

You need a way to notify the viewController that it should pop to it's navigation controller's root view controller.

Now, since each request also includes the username and password for the user, the situation where you would want to notify this could arise in any request whatsoever.

My suggestion is to use [`NSNotificationCenter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/), a class which allows you to broadcast messages to anyone listening for them in your application.

For example, let's call this notification "XYZLogOut".

In your viewController's `-viewWillAppear` method, register it as an observer for this notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(shouldLogOut) name:@"XYZLogOut" object:nil];
```

Make sure to remove the viewController as the observer in the `-viewWillDisappear:` method:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

Note that you need to create a method with the same selector name which will be invoked when that notification is broadcasted.

```
-(void)shouldLogOut
{
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Finally, in the XYZUploader class, you should call this notification when the logout needs to occur:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"XYZLogOut" object:nil userInfo:nil];
```

Comment: Ok if I understand correctly I should create a class XYZLogOut with a subclass of NSNotificationCenter which holds the shouldLogOut function and add the viewWillAppear and viewWillDisappear code in my XYZiPad_Login class?